# How to change the default white background in 3D mode inside Altium?

Tags: altium

In the pcb 3d view I want to change the background color from the default white to something more dark, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

View configuration=> Workspace in 3D mode Start/end

Answer (score 2):

Open PCB file, press number 3 (go to 3D mode), then press L. The **view configuration** menu will be opened. Go to end of this menu and look for **system color**. In this section you can change the background color in the 3D view by changing the color of the work space in 3D mode start/end.